# Using python thread as a plain object

Tags: python, multithreading

If i define a python thread extending threading.Thread class and overriding run I can then invoke run() instead of start() and use it in the caller thread instead of a separate one.

i.e.

```
class MyThread(threading.thread):
    def run(self):
        while condition():
            do_something()
```

this code (1) will execute "run" method this in a separate thread

```
t = MyThread()
t.start()
```

this code (2) will execute "run" method in the current thread

```
t = MyThread()
t.run()
```

Are there any practical disadvantages in using this approach in writing code that can be executed in either way? Could invoking directly the "run"  of a Thread object cause memory problems, performance issues or some other unpredictable behavior?

In other words, what are the differences (if any notable, i guess some more memory *will* be allocated but It should be negligible) between invoking the code (2) on MyThread class and another identical class that extends "object" instead of "threading.Tread"

I guess that some (if any) of the more low level differences might depend on the interpreter. In case this is relevant i'm mainly interested in CPython 3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the [code implementing threading.Thread](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/threading.py) class in cpython 3. The init method simply assigns some variables and do not do anything that seems related to actually create a new thread. Therefore we can assume that it should be safe use a threading.Thread object in the proposed manner.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no difference in the behavior of `run` when you're using the `threading.Thread` object, or an object of a `threading.Thread`'s subclass, or an object of any other class that has the `run` method:

> `threading.Thread.start` starts a new thread and then runs `run` in this thread.
>
> `run` starts the activity in the *calling thread*, be it the main thread or another one.

If you run `run` in the main thread, the whole thread will be busy executing the task `run` is supposed to execute, and you won't be able to do anything until the task finishes.

That said, no, there will be no notable differences as the `run` method behaves just like any other method and is executed in the *calling thread*.